# I am trying to implement CRUD operation using spring-boot-JPA-repositories. Stuck on '@Autowire' concept

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**My Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/patientC")
public class PatientController {
    final static Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(PatientController.class);

    @Autowired
    PatientService patientS;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Patient> registerPatient(@RequestBody Patient p){
        patientS.saveP(p);
        logger.debug("Added::"+p);
        return new ResponseEntity<Patient> (p,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**PatientService Class**

```
package com.patient.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.patient.model.Patient;
import com.patient.repository.PatientRepository;

@Service
public class PatientService implements CRUDService<Patient> {
    @Autowired
    PatientRepository PatientR;

    public PatientService() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Patient saveP(Patient entity) {      
        return PatientR.save(entity);
    }
```

**PatientRespository Class**

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, Integer> {

}
```

***Error Which I am getting on executing the program by 'spring-boot:run'***

```
Field PatientR in com.patient.service.PatientService required a bean of type 'com.patient.repository.PatientRepository' that could not be found.

Caused by: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'patientController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'patientS'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'patientService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'PatientR'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.patient.repository.PatientRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Am I using 'Autowired annotation' incorrectly? What changes am I supposed to make in order to execute my program successfully?**

Comment: try to delete `@Repository` annotation on `PatientRepository`

Comment: where is your main class of spring boot application [like this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) and also where is PatientRespository. perhaps it caused by those service,controller,repository classes are not detected by component scan

Comment: @Javvano Yup. I have defined main class as is defined in the link that you provided.
PatientRepository is in repository package.

Comment: @Patrick I tried. Still getting same error.

Comment: what is your package structure ?
like shown below ?
com.patient.service
com.patient.repository
com.patient.controller

if so ,ur main class have to located at "com.patient" or more upper place

Comment: Main class is in com.patient.config.
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.patient")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
}
}
Is this correct?

Comment: @Javvano It worked. :D
 I changed from com.patient.config to com.patient. for main class. and it's working.
Thank You so much! :)